# Changing Text Color of an Element in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, colors, bubble-sort

I have a program that prints out passes of a bubble sort in an array and want to try to add the functionality of showing (via text color change) where the swaps are taking place within the array at each pass. So far everything that I have tried either changes ALL of the text color or changes nothing (as this current example shows). Anyone have any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void sortArrayAscending(int *array, int size);
void printArray(int *array, int);
void printUnsortedArray(int *array, int size);

int main()
{
HANDLE a = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(a, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

string hyphen;
const string progTitle = "Array Sorting Program";
const int numHyphens = 100;

hyphen.assign(numHyphens, '-');

const int size = 8;

int values[size] = { 21, 16, 23, 18, 17, 22, 20, 19 };

cout << hyphen << endl;
cout << "     " << progTitle << endl;
cout << hyphen << endl;

cout << "\n  This program will sort two identical arrays of numbers using a Bubble Sort"<< endl;


cout << "\n  Array 1 -- Ascending Order:   \n" << endl;

printUnsortedArray(values, size);

cout  << endl;
sortArrayAscending(values, size);

cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
cout << "\n\n\n\nPress only the 'Enter' key to exit program: ";
cin.get();
}

void sortArrayAscending(int *array, int size)
{
const int regTextColor = 2;
const int swapTextColorChange = 4;

HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

int temp;
bool swapTookPlace;
int pass = 0;

do
{
    swapTookPlace = false;
    for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
    {

        if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
        {

            swapTookPlace = true;
            temp = array[count];
            array[count] = array[count + 1];
            array[count + 1] = temp;


            if (swapTookPlace)
            {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

                if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, swapTextColorChange);
                }
                if (pass < 9)
                {
                    cout << fixed << setw(2) << " Pass #  " << (pass + 1) << " : ";
                    pass += 1;
                    printArray(&array[0], size);
                }
                else if (pass >= 9)
                {
                    cout << fixed << setw(2) << " Pass # " << (pass + 1) << " : ";
                    pass += 1;
                    printArray(&array[0], size);
                }
            }
        }
    }
} while (swapTookPlace);
}

void printArray(int *array, int size)
{
for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
    cout << "      " << array[count] << "   ";
cout << endl;
}

void printUnsortedArray(int *array, int size)
{
cout << " Unsorted    ";
for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
    cout << "      " << array[count] << "   ";
cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a basic color that you want to use when nothing gets swapped (white). You start with that color. Then you save the current attribute settings with:

```
HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO Info;
WORD defaultAttributes = 0;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(handle, &Info);
defaultAttributes = Info.wAttributes;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171(v=vs.85).aspx

You then change color to your swap color when you want to show a swap (like you are already doing) and set back the default attributes when there is no swap with:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, defaultAttributes);
```

**EDITED**

Here is the solution.

Compiled on g++ 5.1.0 with -std=c++11 flag.

Executed from Windows cmd.exe

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void sortArrayAscending(int *array, int size);
void printArray(int *array, bool *swaps, int , HANDLE &, WORD , WORD );
void printUnsortedArray(int *array, int size);

int main()
{
    string hyphen;
    const string progTitle = "Array Sorting Program";
    const int numHyphens = 100;

    hyphen.assign(numHyphens, '-');

    const int size = 8;

    int values[size] = { 21, 16, 23, 18, 17, 22, 20, 19 };

    cout << hyphen  << endl;
    cout << "     " << progTitle << endl;
    cout << hyphen  << endl;

    cout << "\n  This program will sort two identical arrays of numbers using a Bubble Sort"<< endl;


    cout << "\n  Array 1 -- Ascending Order:   \n" << endl;

    printUnsortedArray(values, size);

    cout  << endl;
    sortArrayAscending(values, size);

    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    cout << "\n\n\n\nPress only the 'Enter' key to exit program: ";
    cin.get();
}

void sortArrayAscending(int *array, int size)
{
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    //default config
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO Info;
    WORD defaultAttributes = 0;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(screen, &Info);
    defaultAttributes = Info.wAttributes;

    //swap attribute
    WORD swapAttributes = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;


    const int regTextColor = 2;
    const int swapTextColorChange = 4;

    int temp;
    bool swapTookPlace;
    int pass = 0;

    do
    {
        swapTookPlace = false;
        bool swapped[size];
        //let's initialzie swapped to be all-false at the beginning
        for_each(swapped,swapped+size,[](bool &b){b = false;});
        for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); ++count)
        {

            if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
            {
                swapTookPlace = true;
                std::swap(array[count],array[count+1]);
                swapped[count] = true;
                swapped[count+1] = true;
            }else{
                swapped[count] =  swapped[count] | false; //set to unswapped unless previously set to swapped
                swapped[count+1] = false;
            }
        }
        cout << "  Pass #  " << pass;
        printArray(array,swapped,size, screen, defaultAttributes, swapAttributes);
        pass++;
    } while (swapTookPlace);
}

void printArray(int *array, bool *swaps, int size, HANDLE &handle, WORD defaultConfig, WORD swapConfig)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count){
        if (swaps[count]){
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle,swapConfig);
        }else{
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle,defaultConfig);
        }
        cout << "      " << array[count] << "   ";
    }
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle,defaultConfig);
    cout << endl;
}

void printUnsortedArray(int *array, int size)
{
    cout << "  Unsorted ";
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count){
        cout << "      " << array[count] << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: This code dereferences an uninitialized pointer. Instead you could just use a `WORD`, not a pointer

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am incredibly new to C++ and programming and so I have a few questions about your solution:where do these lines go within the program? I tried implementing it in one or the other and couldn't get the program to run. My second question is whether this solution would be capable of formatting only the element in the array that swapped order, for example, if I have an array `{1, 3, 2, 4}` and am sorting in ascending order but want to only color the `[3]` and `[2]` since they would be the items swapping place.

Comment: Happy to help. Ok so in your program that are points when you are writing to the console. You are doing so successfully or I wouldn't have been able to see all the lines with the bubble sort iteration when I ran your code. Now what you need to do is, before writing to the console, to set the color that you want to use. If swapTookPlace = true, then we want to use the green color. otherwise, we want to use the default color. 
At the beginning of the program you will use my first block of code to get the default configuration (defaultAttributes). Then you will create another  configuration [..]

Comment: [...] WORD swapAttribute = FOREGROUND_GREEN | ANY_OTHER_PARAMETER THAT YOU WANT;

At this point, you will use one attribute or the other depending on whether there's a swap or not, as I said above. You would do so with the second block of code that I provided. Which is also what you use in your own code. Keep at it, you'll get it to work.

Comment: Thank you, Ed. This is really helpful. I was able to get the code working... but I think my `if()` loops must be incorrect because when I compile the program the text color does change but it changes _all_ of the values within the array instead of just those that have swapped. Should I be using some form of `for()` loops instead for this, and how exactly would that flesh out to only target certain elements?

Comment: Mate, I edited my answer with the complete solution. Spend some time comparing it with your own as an exercise and thinking about the differences.